# VueJs, How to build and deal with one root component with 6 different modals in it

Tags: vuejs2, refactoring, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have one app with one major root component, the *Editor*. This *Editor* allows adding, editing and removing *rows* and *columns*. Rows have names but columns have name and limit (number).

```
Row(name:string)
Column(name:string, limit:number)
```

When adding or editing a *row* or a *column* I have to open the form in a modal. When remove one, I have to display a confirmation dialog.

```
+-- Editor ---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                         |
|  +-- {{Add|Edit}} row ----+                                             |
|  |                        |                                             |
|  | name: [..............] |    +-- Confirm delete of {{row|column}} -+  |
|  |         [Cancel][Save] |    | Confirm deletion of {{row|column}}? |  |
|  +------------------------+    |                           [No][Yes] |  |
|                                +-------------------------------------+  |
|  +-- {{Add|Edit}} column -+                                             |
|  |                        |                                             |
|  |  name: [.............] |                                             |
|  | limit: [...]           |                                             |
|  |         [Cancel][Save] |                                             |
|  +------------------------+                                             |
|                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

--

Actually I have a `ModalManager` that is too generic and compute the model and title of the modal (or confirmation dialog) based on the *subject* (*row* or *column*) and *action* (*add*, *edit*, *delete*).

Two *Modal* components with custom form and one *Confirmation* component are driven by the `ModalManager`:

```
<Confirmation v-if="manager.mode==='CONFIRM'" 
    title="manager.title"></Confirmation>
<Modal v-if="manager.model='ROW' && manager.mode!=='CONFIRM'
    title="manager.title">
  <!-- form for row with v-model="manager.model" -->
</Modal>
<Modal v-if="manager.model='COLUMN' && manager.mode!=='CONFIRM'
    title="manager.title">
  <!-- form for column with v-model="manager.model" -->
</Modal>
```

As you can imagine, this is a mess and I would like to refactor that to something better. But I do not have enough experience with Vue to have a good view on the possibilities.

I can have a separate model/controler for each modal OR use my Vuex store OR use the vue-router. But, again, I have no clue on how to do it.

--

What can I do to improve my code and manage which modal is shown and the actions linked to them ?

**Edit:**
I am afraid, I was not asking on "how to create a modal". But how to manage complex state inside one root component.

Comment: I would recommend using one of [these nice components](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#overlay) rather than reinventing the wheel. They have quite a variety of selections to choose from. You could add your form/contents in the modal as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component for your specific needs. Something like this should get you started.

```vue
<template>
   <div class="modal" v-if="show">
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <div class="content" v-html="content">
         <!-- Remove this if you don't need complex content -->
         <slot></slot>
      </div>

      <div role="group">
         <button @click="submit">Save</button>
         <button @click="close">Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: 'Modal',

      data() {
         return {
            show: false,
            title: '',
            content: '' // <- Accepts both HTML and plain text (as message)
         }
      },

      methods: {
         toggle(state) {
            this.show = state;  
         },

         open(title, content) {
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;

            this.toggle(true);
         },

         close() {
            this.toggle(false);
         },

         submit() {
            // Handle form submission here
            this.close();
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

### JS

```js
import Modal from './components/Modal.vue';

const vm = new Vue({
   methods: {
      editItem() {
         this.$refs.modal.open('Title', 'Content here');
      }
   },

   components: {
      Modal
   }
})
```

### HTML

```html
<table>
   <!-- rows and stuff -->
</table>

<!-- Add a `ref` so that it can be referenced later -->
<modal ref="modal"></modal>

<button @click.prevent="editItem">Edit item</button>
```